# laravel 7 destroy route not working , it redirect me to the show route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

when i try to delete a user it redirect me to the user profile ( show method)
its not showing any errors , but it behaves like i asked for the show method

the route

```
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
```

the link to the destroy method

```
 <a href="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}">delete</>
```

the destroy method in the controller

```
 public function destroy($id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->delete();
            return redirect('/users')->with('success','Utilisateur est supprimé');
        }
```

i tried excluding the destroy method from the ressource routes and creating it seperatly but it dont work

Comment: With the <a> tag you are sending a `get` request. Use a <form> instead, with a input named `_method` with value `delete`

Comment: didnt get you , can u please write it for me

Answer (score 3):

With the `<a>` tag you are sending a get request. So it could be used to get route like the show route:

```
<a href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}">show</>
```

For delete, use a `<form>` instead, with a input named `_method` with value `delete`, and `csrf` field:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <button type="submit">delete</button> 
</form>
```

You can read more on the docs:
[Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)
[Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Destroy method requires "delete" request method and cant be achieved with

```
<a href="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}">delete</a>

so use this instead

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="submit">delete</button> 
</form>
```